# how to write MPEG4 video files from stream in vc++ directshow

Tags: visual-c++, directshow

hai all...

```
    Am writing simple application for capturing video from camera and save in .WMV files using vc++ Directshow.i done this task.bt i need to write file as MPEG4 file type.
```

can anyone help me.

```
  CAMERA---->SAMPLEGRABBER---->getting streams from sample graaper..
```

i get stream from camera like this.

kndly help me
thanks

Answer (score 2):

if you camera produces compressed video, you can build a graph camera => mux => file writer. You can download a mux for MP4 files from www.gdcl.co.uk/mpeg4. But probably you will need to find an encoder for mpeg-4 or H264 -- look at ffmpeg for that.